# Fix Pinterest CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, pinterest

I am trying to create custom button for pinterest. I was able to use a custom image as a button but it is not working properly.

Here is the CSS I am using.

```
span[data-pin-log="button_pinit_bookmarklet"] {
}
span[data-pin-log="button_pinit_bookmarklet"]::after {
  content: url('../images/icon.png');
}
```

[image: The ScreenShot]

In the ScreenShot I have marked the button I am working on using red color. I have marked the areas I want to get rid off using blue color.

I am stuck on this problem for more than 12 hours. So, any help will be really appreciated.

You can get the Pinterest Button Using these codes

```
<a data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"></a>
<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you expected this result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lvDa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For custom button

---

The `data-pin-custom="true"` attribute is important because it keeps your custom markup, including your `HTML and CSS`.

```
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"
   data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"
   data-pin-custom="true">
    --YOUR CUSTOM HTML--
</a>
```

--YOUR CUSTOM HTML-- Given likes as below

```
<img src="https://developers.pinterest.com/static/img/badge.svg" width="25" height="25">
```

```html
<p>Ordinary button</p>

<a data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"></a>
<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>

<p>Custom button</p>

<a data-pin-do="buttonPin" href="" data-pin-custom="true">
  <img src="https://developers.pinterest.com/static/img/badge.svg" width="25" height="25">
</a>
```

**For more information**: Visit **https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/?**

Comment: @Lily Nicole Talmers check this .